# With QToolBox, which setting to have page be only its content size?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to find the settings or size policy so that each page in my `QToolBox` instance only takes up the space needed by its content. I've tried everything I could see in the properties for both the instance and for each of the individual pages.

**Am I misconstruing the functionality of `QToolBox` widget or just missing the right setting?**

What I am going for is something similar to the accordion fold type widget in Qt Creator:

[image]

I can't seem to get this "Sort" page to take only the size needed to display the button and field.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that directly because it will span all the available space that the title widgets don't occupy. You can emulate what you want by setting a [fixed height](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight) on the `QToolBox` if you know the exact height your page(s). But you **do not** want to do that in practise.

If you want the behavior you ask for then you need to write your own custom control. It doesn't have to be hard. Use a `QVBoxLayout` and fill into it items of a custom class, let's call it `ToolItem`, which is a `QWidget` with a title (perhaps a button to show/hide) and another `QWidget` for showing the contents that is either visible or not.

The following **very simple** example will toggle the visibility of the `ToolItem` when it is clicked. And only when visible will it occupy any space.

```
class ToolItem : public QWidget {
public:
  ToolItem(const QString &title, QWidget *item) : item(item) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(new QLabel(title));
    layout->addWidget(item);    
    setLayout(layout);

    item->setVisible(false);
  }

protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    item->setVisible(!item->isVisible());
  }

private:
  QWidget *item;
};

class ToolBox : public QWidget {
public:
  ToolBox() : layout(new QVBoxLayout) {
    setLayout(layout);
  }

  void addItem(ToolItem *item) {
    // Remove last spacer item if present.
    int count = layout->count();
    if (count > 1) {
      layout->removeItem(layout->itemAt(count - 1));
    }

    // Add item and make sure it stretches the remaining space.
    layout->addWidget(item);    
    layout->addStretch();
  }

private:
  QVBoxLayout *layout;
};
```

And simple usage of it:

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
window->setWindowTitle("QToolBox Example");

QListWidget *list = new QListWidget;
list->addItem("One");
list->addItem("Two");
list->addItem("Three");

ToolBox *toolBox = new ToolBox;
toolBox->addItem(new ToolItem("Title 1", new QLabel("Some text here")));
toolBox->addItem(new ToolItem("Title 2", list));
toolBox->addItem(new ToolItem("Title 3", new QLabel("Lorem Ipsum..")));  

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(toolBox);

window->setLayout(layout);
window->resize(500, 500);
window->show();
```

You can now tweak it to look like the `QToolBox` if needed.

Please don't hesitate to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Wow, great example; really learning  a lot from it. Thanks! I'm new to Qt and layouts have been the hardest to get an intuitive sense of. You've set out the relationships here in a way that finally clicks for me. Finally, I'm pretty much a punter/hobbyist with C++. You're using only .h files here (at least I did to get this working). I have always used the .cpp + .h together. Is there a name for just using the .h so I can look it up? I saw something called the "pimpl idiom" but I not sure if that is what this is.

Comment: You are very welcome. :) Yeah I just put it like this to be as clear as possible. You can have everything in a .h file but then it essentially just becomes the implementation file anyway. It is better to have .h files (with include guards) that you can expose interface with and then .cpp files with the actual implementation. In some instances you'll have some implementation in the .h files anyway, like when using templates. PIMPL still uses .h/.cpp files.

Answer (score 4):

The example shown from Qt Designer may not be using a `QToolBox`, which behaves more like a stacked tab widget only displaying a single page at a time. The example in Qt Designer appears to be a `QTreeWidget` with custom drawing or styling.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete answer.

I traced down the actual component, it can be included outside designer (kind of). Here is a minimal example showing how to do that (modified from https://github.com/zdenekzc/qtdesigner-integration).

[image]

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class FormWindow : public QMainWindow {
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
       explicit FormWindow (QWidget * parent = 0);
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

form.cc

```
#include "form.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDesigner/QtDesigner>
#include <QtDesigner/QDesignerComponents>

FormWindow::FormWindow (QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow (parent) {
   QDesignerFormEditorInterface* core = QDesignerComponents::createFormEditor (this);
   core->setWidgetBox (QDesignerComponents::createWidgetBox (core, 0));
   this->setCentralWidget (core->widgetBox());
}

extern "C" int main (int argc, char * * argv) {
   QApplication app (argc, argv);
   FormWindow * win = new FormWindow ();
   win->show ();
   return app.exec();
}
```

qt-designer.pro

```
QT       += designer
HEADERS  = form.h
SOURCES  = form.cc
LIBS     += -lQt5DesignerComponents
```

Build it:

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
qmake-qt5 ../qt5-design.pro
make
./qt5-design
```

This is obviously not useful by itself unless you want to build a designer but another step towards isolating the actual component.